# Swift - How to correctly set up a Weak Variable

Tags: xcode, automatic-ref-counting

I have an app with a lot of Astronomical calculations in them.
For sanity they are separated into individual methods/functions.
Run individually there are no memory runaways.

HOWEVER when I need to calculate something complex like the angle of incidence of the sun's rays to any place on the Earth I have to call 19 methods in a row and the memory usage goes through the roof. Clearly variables are still live so the ARC can't evaporate them.

So I presumed the solution was to create a weak link. If I change my call from

```
var angleIncidence = Celestial().calculateAngleIncidence(....)
```

to

```
weak var angleIncidence = Celestial().calculateAngleIncidence(....)
```

I get a "Weak cannot be applied to a non class type Double".

I am clearly being too naive.

Comment: How do you know memory goes through the roof? Are you actually using instruments or the gauges in Xcode? Is there an actual performance problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doubles are not objects, so referring to them as strong and weak does not make sense because they do not have reference counts.

In practice, they obey the typical rules of variable scope. However, they should really not be a cause for significant memory usage, unless you are using very large arrays of them. My feeling is that something else is probably going on - probably to do with other data types present and how data is being passed between the functions.

Comment: Good point. I am dealing with low hundreds of Doubles but not a single String. What is happening in the above call is that it is calling a func that in turn calls 19 other methods one after another. Is that bad practice?I am eating about 4MB of memory on each call, and not an array in sight.

Comment: Without seeing the exact structure, it's hard to say. But: 1) 19 methods is probably too many, if only from a code readability standpoint, and it may be an idea to refactor the code 2) 4MB is not that much. I suggest asking a further question with more explicit details about the code if you want more assistance.

Comment: Will decompose the code and see where the culprit is. Many thanks.